# endWhile is not working, can't start without editing index in while

Tags: selenium, while-loop, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I'm using Katalon Recorder extension for Chrome,

My code is working in some weird way, to start my test first I have to just edit (even click and add/remove space) the step with start while loop.
Second thing is that after the endWhile the test is not stopped but continue with null in variable.
Any suggestions what is wrong (it may be a silly question as I'm quite fresh in using it).

This for checking on site the list of some domains which shouldn't be acceptable by the email field.

```
import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint as Checkpoint
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory as CheckpointFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords as MobileBuiltInKeywords
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling as FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase as TestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory as TestCaseFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData as TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory as TestDataFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository as ObjectRepository
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WSBuiltInKeywords
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory as DriverFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUiBuiltInKeywords
import internal.GlobalVariable as GlobalVariable
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.WebDriverBackedSelenium
import static org.junit.Assert.*
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join

WebUI.openBrowser('https://www.katalon.com/')
def driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
String baseUrl = "https://www.katalon.com/"
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl)
String  = selenium.getEval("index=0")
selenium.open("https://someportal/#/login")
selenium.click("link=Sign up")
String domainList = selenium.getEval("['0-mail.com','027168.com','0815.su','0sg.net','10mail.org','10minutemail.co.za','11mail.com','123.com','123box.net','123india.com','123mail.cl','123mail.org','123qwe.co.uk','126.com','139.com','150mail.com','150ml.com','15meg4free.com','163.com','16mail.com','188.com','189.cn','1ce.us','1chuan.com','1coolplace.com','1freeemail.com','1funplace.com','1internetdrive.com','1mail.ml','1mail.net','1me.net','1mum.com','1musicrow.com', and many many more domains in this array...']")

selenium.click("id=email")
selenium.while("(index=0, index <= storedVars['domainList'].length)")
String temp = selenium.getEval("index+1")
String finalCount = selenium.getEval("temp")
System.out.println(selenium.getEval("'" + domainList + "'['" + temp + "']"));
String forbiddenMail = selenium.getEval("domainList[index++]")
selenium.type("id=email", "kamtest@" + forbiddenMail)
selenium.click("id=password")
selenium.type("id=password", "ZAQ!2wsx")
selenium.click("id=confirmpassword")
selenium.type("id=confirmpassword", "ZAQ!2wsx")
selenium.click("xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='mail_outline'])[1]/preceding::h2[1]")
verifyEquals("Please enter your business email address. This form does not accept addresses from free email domains", selenium.getText("xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Email Address'])[1]/following::small[2]"));
selenium.click("name=tc")
selenium.click("name=submit")
selenium.click("xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='mail_outline'])[1]/preceding::h2[1]")
verifyEquals("Please enter your business email address. This form does not accept addresses from free email domains", selenium.getText("xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Email Address'])[1]/following::small[2]"));
selenium.open("https://someportal.com/#/login")
selenium.click("link=Sign up")
selenium.endWhile()
```

After all domains are checked (over 4700) the test continue with null instead of stop the test.
Test can't be started without edit while(index), got first result, index is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your while condition

You should use **`<`** instead of **`<=`**

```
selenium.while("(index=0, index < storedVars['domainList'].length)")
```

`length` returns the number of elements in the array, but since the indexing is zero-based, the index of the last element will be the length - 1